# Find if any value in a list exists in another list

Tags: groovy

im a newbie in groovy so i have a question, i have two lists, and i want to know if a value that exists in the first list also exists in the second list, and it must return true or false.

I tried to make a short test but it doesn't works... here is what i tried:

```
// List 1
def modes = ["custom","not_specified","me2"]
// List 2
def modesConf = ["me1", "me2"]
// Bool
def test = false

test = modesConf.any { it =~ modes }
print test
```

but if i change the value of "me2" in the first array to "mex2" it returns true when it must return false

Any idea?

Answer (score 14):

Simplest I can think of is using `intersect` and let Groovy truth kick in.

```
def modes = ["custom","not_specified","me2"]
def modesConf = ["me1", "me2"]
def otherList = ["mex1"]

assert modesConf.intersect(modes) //["me2"]
assert !otherList.intersect(modes) //[]

assert modesConf.intersect(modes) == ["me2"]
```

In case the assertion passed, you can get the common elements out of the intersection without doing a second operation. :)

Answer (score 10):

I believe you want:

```
// List 1
def modes = ["custom","not_specified","me2"]
// List 2
def modesConf = ["me1", "me2"]

def test = modesConf.any { modes.contains( it ) }
print test
```

Answer (score 8):

This `disjoint()` method returns `true` if there's no item that is common to both lists. It sounds like you want the negation of that:

```
def modes = ["custom","not_specified","me2"]
def modesConf = ["me1", "me2"]
assert modes.disjoint(modesConf) == false

modesConf = ["me1", "mex2"]
assert modes.disjoint(modesConf) == true
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use any of the disjoint()/intersect()/any({}) which will return true/false. Below given are the examples:

```
def list1=[1,2,3]

def list2=[3,4,5]
list1.disjoint(list2) // true means there is no common elements false means there is/are
list1.any{list2.contains(it)} //true means there are common elements

list1.intersect(list2) //[] empty list means there is no common element.
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def missingItem = modesConf.find { !modes.contains(it) }

assert missingFile == "me1"
```

In such case, missingItem will contain a missing element which exists in modesConf but doesn't exist in modes. Or will be null if everything is fine.

Comment: This only returns the first element that is missing, not all. If anyone wants to find all elements that are different, replace `find` with `findAll`